# Logging in as user using discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make some simple program, showing received messages through the terminal. Now I am trying to ask the user for their email address and password for the login, but some errors occur, which I do not quite understand. This is what my code looks like:

```
import discord


class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        discord.Client.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Success!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dc = DiscordClient()
    dc.login(input('email : '), input('password : '), bot=False)
    dc.run()
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/Main.py", line 16, in <module>
    dc.run()
  File "[...]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "[...]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 490, in start
    yield from self.login(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 418, in login
    raise TypeError('login() takes 1 or 2 positional arguments but {} were given'.format(n))
TypeError: login() takes 1 or 2 positional arguments but 0 were given
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x103881fd0>
```

So, what am I doing wrong, or what should code look like? All I was doing was write an `on_message()` and some basic commands like `send_message()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`client.login` is a coroutine  so it should be (untested) :

```py
await dc.login(input('email : '), input('password : '), bot=False)
```

Note that in this case, *bot* parameter is not needed.
However, to use **client.login**, you need to use the *client loop*. To avoid that, you can simply do:

```py
dc.run(email, password)
```

Which will both login and connect and then start the loop.

After that you can (in the *on_ready* function) get a desired server from **dc.servers** and a suitable channel to send there, for example, a 'Hello message' with **dc.send_message**.

When you are done with the connection, do **self.close()** from within the *DiscordClient* class.

Working example for **Python 3.4** (replace keywords as necessary for Python 3.6)

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime


class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        discord.Client.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def on_ready(self):
        servers = list(self.servers)
        for server in servers:
            if server.name == 'My server':
                break

        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.name == 'general':
                break

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        yield from self.send_message(channel, 'Api Success! at ' + str(now))
        print('Success!')
        yield from self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dc = DiscordClient()
    email = input('email : ')
    password = input('password : ')
    dc.run(email, password)
```