# Discord.py: How to print last message on specific channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

my code is this but output is terrible

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(f'Connected to Discord!')
 channel = client.get_channel(231231321213)
 messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
 print(messages)
 
 


client.run('token', bot=False)
```

My Output:

Connected to Discord!
[<Message id=826111938424864848 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author= flags=>]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\cinar\untitled0.py", line 18, in 
client.run('Bot Token', bot=False)

File "D:\Users\cinar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 714, in run
_cleanup_loop(loop)

File "D:\Users\cinar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 95, in _cleanup_loop
loop.close()

File "D:\Users\cinar\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 89, in close
raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")

RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

Comment: what do you mean by "the output is horrible"? What's the result? What's the expected result? Takea  look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes ı mean output ı edited my message

Comment: I looked at the docs and I find out `history()` yielding `Message` not string, maybe try `message.content`?
Also, I just realize, why do you need `bot = False`? Like, are you trying to self bot?

Comment: yes ı am trying to make selfbot. how can ı use message.content to get last messages string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do self bot with an actual bot token, I'm not gonna recommend continuing this as self botting is against ToS. But if you really want to do it anyway, use your email and password instead of a bot token. I'm gonna warn you once again that self botting is against ToS and might get your account banned, so do this at your own risk. Anyway someone already asked how to log in as a user [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54865874/14310037)

Also as I said in the comment earlier, I looked into discord.py docs and found out `history()` is yielding message. So maybe you should try to do `print(message[0].content)` instead.

Comment: ' messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
 print(messages.content)  '                                                                                                             I tryed this one but ı got an error:                                                                                        ' AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'content'  '

Comment: Sorry I forgot flatten() make a list, anyway my answer has updated.